# Context database and Sharepoint in C# console app

Tags: c#, sharepoint

In short:
I have a C# console app which i used to test and write data from SQL to SharePoint lists.

Everything works fine while it is ran as console app. I get the connection towards SQL, context is created, then I connect to SharePoint site and proceed with update of certain fields.

Now, when I deploy working solution as a timerjob (a .wsp) for sharepoint, and when I update it to the server farm and deploy it as feature to the site, and run it as a timerjob, it does work, but only, so to speak "once".

When I run that timer job, it recives SQL context, connects, and updates SharePoint lists. But when I change data in a SQL table (eg. a field called "price" from 10.99 to 11.99), and run timerjob again, it still only updates the "old" data, to be exact, the 10.99 value.

Now when doing this with console app .exe, on the server, no matter how many db changes I perform, it always updates the newest data, but as a timerJob it seems like it "hanges" onto previous context connection, and updates previous data only.

Do I need to specify, in the code, to drop context after the timerjob has ended it's run, so it can call the same but "fresh" context on the next run.

Here is inital code in the .wsp

```
    class TimerJobPromoToolsDefinition : SPJobDefinition
        {

    public TimerJobPromoToolsDefinition() : base()
    {

    }

    public TimerJobPromoToolsDefinition(string jobName, SPService service) : base(jobName, service, null, SPJobLockType.None)
    {
        this.Title = "PromoTools_Timer_Job";
    }


    public TimerJobPromoToolsDefinition(string jobName, SPWebApplication webapp) : base(jobName, webapp, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
    {
        this.Title = "PromoTools_Timer_Job";
    }

    public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Assert(false);

        Main();
    }

    private static TimerJobConnection _context; 

    public static void Main()
    {
        PrintInitializing();

        _context = new TimerJobConnection();

        string siteURL = "http://somesite.com/";

        try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {

                    var catalogs = GetArtikliFromPromoTools(web);

                    var articlesFiltered = GetArtikliFromDB(catalogs);

                    PrintFinishedLoadingArticles();

                    GetSharePointCatalogHeaders(web);

                    UpdateArticles(catalogs, articlesFiltered, web);

                    PrintEndOfOperation();

                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            PrintErrorSharepointConnection();
            PrintPressKeyToExit();
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the "context" should not the issue based on my experience.

As you catched the exception, try to check is any exception, You could try to debug the code by attaching to [owstimer](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013-programmatically-using-server-side-object/) process also.